# How can I include tweets in a carousel using Twitter-Post-Fetcher?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I'm using Twitter-Post-Fetcher by Jason Mayes (http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/) and I would like to display tweets one-by-one in a carousel.
Currently my carousel plugin is slick.js (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), and I intended to use it in "single-item" mode.

Slick html:

```
 <div class="single-item">
    <div id="example4></div>
    <div id="example5"></div>
    <div id="example6"></div>
 </div>
```

Slick jquery:

```
$('.single-item').slick();
```

By default, Twitter-Fetcher uses ID to identify and show tweets. In my case I used as "placeholder" three configurations with the same ID, but imagine they are different:

```
var config4 = {
 "id": '988087557270507521',
 "domId": 'example4', 
 "maxTweets": 5,
 "enableLinks": true,
 "showUser": true,
 "showTime": false,
 "dateFunction": dateFormatter,
 "showRetweet": false
};

twitterFetcher.fetch(config4);


var config5 = {
 "id": '988087557270507521',
 "domId": 'example5', 
 "maxTweets": 5,
 "enableLinks": true,
 "showUser": true,
 "showTime": false,
 "dateFunction": dateFormatter,
 "showRetweet": false
};

twitterFetcher.fetch(config5);


var config6 = {
 "id": '988087557270507521',
 "domId": 'example6', 
 "maxTweets": 5,
 "enableLinks": true,
 "showUser": true,
 "showTime": false,
 "dateFunction": dateFormatter,
 "showRetweet": false
};

twitterFetcher.fetch(config6);
```

How can I have a carousel for each configuration?

Comment: What carousel plugin or package are you using? Or are you trying to create your own from scratch? What framework are you using? Need a bit more info.

Comment: Thanks Chase, I added some information about the plugin. I'm afraid I can't be more specific right now. I hope it can be enough.

Comment: Seems like you got the right idea. What were you trying to display in the carousel? Looks like you'll have to create an array and store the results from each `twitterFetcher.fetch` and use that to populate some html.